# error in mysql8 trying to change permissions for root user for allowing remote connections

Tags: mysql

I updated to MySQL 8.3 and would like to set it up for allowing remote connections.

I was using where $PASSWORD is the password but am getting the following error and am a bit confused. Any idea what is should be?

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$PASSWORD';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY ''' at line 1
mysql>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the user first then add the privileges

```
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$PASSWORD';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: You may want `WITH GRANT OPTION`, too.